# What is the correct way of executing a java command from RunTime.exec()

Tags: java

I need to run command using Runtime.exec() :

```
java -cp .:/s/v-lib/* tDesigner -inRs /scg.rsp -out /g.plan;
```

here i need to add all the jars present in /s/v-lib directory to my class path. 
Do i need to add them individually?

`tDesigner` is my class.
`-inRs /scg.rsp -out /g.plan` are the arguments to the class.

what will be the correct way to construct command string?
is this correct:

```
String[] command = {"java", "-cp", ".:/s/v-lib/*", "tDesigner" ,"-inRs", "/scg.rsp" ,"-out", "g.plan"};
```

Comment: Usually it's best to stick to a single question per ... well, question. I see two here: One about classpaths, the other about `Runtime.exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invocation of `exec()` looks correct.

Regarding the classpath, since java 1.5 you may specify a *directory* (rather than jars) in the classpath, in which case all jars found there are added to the classpath.